# Swift - Firestore auto create collection/document

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to create a collection or document automatically?

In my case I already have a `collection` ("users") and in it are all of the the users.
What I would like to achieve is if the user clicks on a button several `subcollections` and also an empty `document` should be created.

I tried this but is failing:

```
func insertWish(){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("wishlists").document("Main Wishlist").collection("Wünsche").document("Laptop").setData(["": ""]) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

These collections/document do not exist in my database and should only be created if the user clicks the button:

```
collection("wishlists").document("Main Wishlist").collection("Wünsche").document("Laptop")
```

Comment: What is failing? Is there an error message? What exactly do you expect the code to do?

Comment: the collections/documents do not get created and it prints the "error" message

Comment: What is the error?  The variable `error`.  It will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: oh I forgot about that! That is the error: Optional("The property.name is the empty string.")

Comment: fixed that issue thanks :) There is however another problem after I created a document like this. If you could have a look at @DougStevenson answer

Comment: If you have additional questions, please post them separately.  Stack Overflow is not a forum for ongoing support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message "The property.name is the empty string" is telling you that you're trying to add an invalid document:

```
setData(["": ""])
```

A field name of empty string is not valid.  Give it a name that conforms to the requirements in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields).

Comment: is there a way to create an empty document?

Comment: `setData([])` with no fields

Comment: ok that actually works now. But inside Firestore in the created document it says that the document is "not available" and it will not be shown in snapshots or querys.

Comment: If you don't add any fields, there won't be a query that can find it.  You can `get` the document, but it won't be searchable.

Comment: If you have followup questions, please post them separately.  Comments are not well suited to continuing questions.

Comment: will do that, youre right thats another question :) Thanks for you answer